# Get color of span class inside h1 tag

Tags: python, html, css, selenium

I want to get the color of all instances of header elements in a webpage using Selenium.

For `h1` elements for example, if I try:

```
h1 = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('h1')
color = elem_tag.value_of_css_property('color')
```

It gives me the value of only one color, and it is not even the one I see when I inspect the element. I understood it is because it is overwritten. So I think what I need to do is get the color of the instance [?].

I see that inside the `h1` tag there is this span class, but I do not know how to get its color:

```
<h1 class="ccl-2a4b5924 ccl-29aecca026 ccl-a1841d8ca6 ccl-0338edd3d4 ccl-61059584b">
    <span class="example_class-5c86233">SOME TEXT</span>
</h1>
```

How do I get the color of "SOME TEXT" that is shown on the webpage?

Comment: While I don't know Selenium, in Javascript you would have to loop over those elements to return the value for each of them. I assume it is the same case here.

Comment: Can you provide the URL?

Comment: @SwaroopHumane here it goes: https://deliveroo.be/en/

Comment: @LucasFarias Only 1 h1 tag is available in the front page. FYI

Comment: @SwaroopHumane Nice, but why am I getting the "wrong" color value then, the one that is later overwritten?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you are looking for -

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.color import Color

rgb = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//h1/span").value_of_css_property('color')
hex = Color.from_string(rgb).hex
print("HEX:- " + hex)
```

Please mark it as answer if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: It returns the same color value as the code I'm using (i.e. #ffffff), but I want #440063.